# Jquery Drag and Drop on Sortable

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I need help getting a drag and drop function to work.  I have a form builder that works as follows.  You drag and drop a Fieldset from the left list into the "work area".  You can drag and drop multiple fieldsets into the work area and then reorder/sort them.  Once in the work area, you can drop a "Field" from the bottom left menu into the fieldsets you just dropped into the work area.

I want to be able to move a dropped field from one fieldset to another within the work area.  For example, I placed a field in the wrong fieldset and want to move it.  However, I cannot move the field once it is dropped into a fieldset.  Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.  Fsfiddle link and code below.

[Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/humphrey_brent/hdb0epx6/91/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fs_count = 0;
  $("#drop-area").droppable({
    accept: '.ui-draggable:not(.draggableField)',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        fs_count++;
      var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone()
      clone.addClass('.connectedSortable')
      // clone.removeClass('.ui-draggable');
      if (clone.hasClass('dropped')) {
            return false;
        }
        clone.addClass('.connectedSortable').addClass('dropped').attr('id', 'fs_' + fs_count);
      $(this).append(clone);

      var fieldsDroppable = $('#drop-area .ui-draggable:last-child .fieldDroppable');
      fieldsDroppable.droppable({
      accept: '.draggableField',
          drop: function(event, ui) {
              var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone();
              $(this).append(clone);
          }
});

    }
  });

    $(".fieldDroppable").droppable({
    accept: '.draggableField',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone()
      $(this).append(clone);
    }
  });

  $(".ui-draggable").draggable({
    opacity: 1.0,
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
  });
    $(".draggableField").draggable({
    opacity: 1.0,
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'false'
  });

  $("#drop-area").sortable({ 
    handle: '.drag-handle',
    update: function () { //triggered when sorting stopped
    var dataAuto = $("#drop-area").sortable("serialize", {
            key: "za",
            attribute: "id",
        });
            alert(dataAuto);  
    }
  });

  $("#drop-area").disableSelection();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do. For all the fields dropped into fieldsets in working area, add a remove button which deletes that particular field in that particular fieldset and later you can add the same field in another fieldset.

Comment: A,field may be configured and tied to functions so deleting it could be a problem.  I am hoping to figure out how to drag and drop it to other fieldsets.

Comment: While dragging a field to a workplace, you will be binding it to certain events, what problems will you face while deleting it? You can always attach the same events while re-dropping the same field again.

Comment: The field will eventually contain a form field.  That form field has properties that will be customized and saved to a database.  That custom field then feeds a contract generation script that looks for that specific field and runs scripts based on the customized field properties.  Do deleting it would disrupt processes downstream.

Comment: I should mention that after the form is built,  it is saved to the database.  This same script I am building will also be used to modify saved forms eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Please review this answer

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" >
    <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header" style="height: 300px;width: 300px;">
    <div id="droppable1" class="ui-widget-header ui-droppable" style="height: 150px;">
        <p>Cleared!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="droppable2" class="ui-widget-header ui-droppable ui-state-highlight" style="height: 150px;">
        <p>Dropped!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here goes the js

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable1, #droppable2" ).droppable({
    out: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-highlight" ).find( "p" ).html( "Cleared!" );
    },
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this ).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" ).find( "p" ).html( "Dropped!" );
    }
});
```

For draggable, use containment to restrict the movement. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for working on it.   While that may work independently, it does not help with my issue.  I think when I drop a field into a fieldset I loose the draggable function.  I don't need to visually acknowledge movement or anything.  Just drag the field from one fieldset to another.